# Thunderbird 3.1.7 file system and file extensions

Tags: email, thunderbird

I have lost all email messages and folders in Mozilla Thunderbird. Where can I look for them? My system is Windows XP.

I have looked in the Thunderbird Profiles default profile folder. I can see Inbox and Trash but none of the other folders I have set up are visible.

I cannot directly open Inbox or Trash so I don't know if my lost messages are in these folders. Is there someone in this community who can help?

Answer (score 0):

The location of the folder can be found by following the instructions on [this link](http://email.about.com/od/mozillathunderbirdtips/qt/Find_Thunderbird_Profile_Dir.htm).

> On Windows:
>
> Select Run... from the Start menu.
>
> Type "%appdata%" (without the quotes).
>
> Hit Return. Open the Thunderbird
> folder. Go to the Profiles folder.
>
> Now
> open the folder of your Mozilla
> Thunderbird profile (probably
> "********.default" where the '*'s
> stand for random characters) and the
> folder beneath it.

As an aside, it's possible over the years that you may have more than one profile folder, so it's worth having a look for other locations in the general vicinity.

As for file types, the extension for Thunderbird mail is `.msf`, with a coinciding file name without an extension that stores the actual data.

You will not be able to view the data by double-clicking on the file, due to the way the data is stored.